# How to access an environment variable in a FOR loop set in same FOR loop?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

This is what I have:

```
FOR /f %%G IN (school\students\%studentname%\classes.txt) DO (
    set /p grade=<"school\students\%studentname%\classes\%%G\grade.txt"
    pause
    echo %grade%
    echo You Have %grade% in %%G
)
pause
```

My problem is that I get back:

```
You have  in Math.
You have  in English.
```

In the grade.txt files I have an A in one and a B in the other. The %%G is set to English and Math throughout the FOR command and find the folders fine. But the %grade% variable is not setting for some reason. I cannot figure out why. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work if I understand your folder structure correctly. Like this:

- **students\name1\class1**
- . . . . . . . .\ . . . . . . \class2
- . . .
- **students\name2\class1**
- . . . . . . . .\ . . . . . . \class2

**. . .** and that  classes.txt is in the name folder and a grade.txt file is in each class folder.

---

```
 @echo off
    set /p studentname="Enter student name: "
    set studentpath=C:\school\students\%studentname%

      For /f %%G in (%studentpath%\classes.txt) do (
        For /f %%i in (%studentpath%\%%G\grade.txt) do (
            echo %studentname% got %%i in %%G
          )
      )

    pause
```

You need to set the correct `studentpath`.

The outer loop reads a class from classes.txt and assigns the value (class name) to %%G. Then the inner loop runs to get the grade for this class, which is assigned to %%i. The result is echoed and we go back to the outer loop for the next class. This gets around the issue of DelayedExpansion ([explained here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)) by not setting any variables inside the for loops, but simply using the parameters %%G and %%i for the output.

**Be aware that this setup of nested loops only works because the inner loop only needs to loop one time--to go fetch the single grade for that single class from grade.txt.**

With "nested for loops, for each iteration of the outer loop **all** iterations of the inner for are executed." [@MCND]. So, for example, if  grade.txt contained the grades for both classes, each on a separate line, like this:
.  a
.  b
the result would be:
.  studentame got a in math
.  studentname got b in math
.  studentame got a in english
.  studentname got b in english

Comment: The above answer did not work, but your original response worked perfectly, with the nested for loops. Thanks again @sjoy And if you could add it back that would be great.

Comment: OK @TonyStark. Rolled back to previous answer. Surprised the set /p method for reading file didn't work since I test everything, but great that this does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need delayed [expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) :

```
@echo off

set "student=school\students\%studentname%\classes.txt"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f %%G IN (%student%) DO (
 set /p grade=<%student%
  pause
 echo !grade!
 echo You Have !grade! in %%G
)
 pause

endlocal
```

but grade will be always the same - `set /p grade=<file` reads only the first line of the file.
And `%%G` will only access the first word of the file.Check the tokens and delims options.

Comment: I should have been a little more clear. Each class has a folder and in it is a grade.txt file. So I wanted %grade% to set to the grade in the text file of each class folder. The class folder to look in I wanted to be determined by the class name in the classes.txt file and then put in the path for the class folder as %%G then %%H an so on. So that each class in classes.txt would be looked in their folders for grade.txt and then the grade echoed. I hope that makes sense. Unless delayed expansion would solve this. But I have no idea what delayed expansion is. Sorry for the lengthy explanation...

Comment: I also tried to use your answer above but it produced the same result.  @npocmaka

Comment: @TonyStark will be easier for you to explain with example

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would have better result if you used `" "` while working with `echo` ?  i.e.  `echo "$VARIBALE"`

Comment: No this did not produce a better result. All I got was `You have "" in Math`